# Having trouble with a statement in sakurai modern qm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am facing trouble with a statement made after eq 5.2.4 in sakurai modern qm and the statement is $P_1(E-H_0-\lambda P_1VP_1)$ is singular in $P_1$ subspace. How one can we show the validity of the statement?

This question is similar to problem asked previously in this forum but haven't answered appropriately. So I am asking again here. The link for the  qn is
[Can't Prove formula from Sakurai's Modern QM @ Perturbation Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30109/cant-prove-formula-from-sakurais-modern-qm-perturbation-theory#)

Comment: Hi sachin, welcome to the PhysicsSE! Questions need to be self-contained, so please state your question directly rather than redirecting users to a link.  If your question is similar to another which has already been asked, you should state precisely why you find existing answers unsatisfactory and what elaboration you are looking for to avoid your question being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I am having trouble by statement made after eq 5.2.4 in sakurai and the statement is P1(E-H0-lambdaP1VP1) is not singular in P1 subspace. How one can show that the statement is valid.

Comment: First, you should update the question, not simply clarify it in a comment.  Second, the accepted answer to the linked question is fairly thorough, so you'd have to explain what about it you don't find acceptable.

Comment: They simply said there is a typo in the qn so, there was not valid answer in the previous post for this query

Comment: There is a typo in the book. Mark goes on to explain why the operator in question is not singular.