# Having trouble in a statement made in sakurai modern qm

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am facing trouble with a statement made after eq 5.2.4 in sakurai modern qm and the statement is $P_1(E-H_0-\lambda P_1VP_1)$ is singular in $P_1$ subspace. How one can we show the validity of the statement.

Comment: Hi sachin rawat. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit [your original question within your original entry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556362/2451).

Comment: Sir previous answers are  not appropriate as you can check. They haven't  prove the statement there

Comment: Sachin, I will take the content of this question and edit into the text of your previous question. This is what @Qmechanic has recommended that you do instead of posting a new question.

Comment: But they closed the post by considering closed as duplicate